# Joining data using pyspark in azure serverless spark

Tags: azure, pyspark

I am using Azure Machine Learning's serverless Spark node, which has 4 vCPUs, 32 GB memory, a 64 GB disk, and 2 executors. In my current task, I am merging two large datasets using PySpark. One dataset is around 15 GB in size, while the other is approximately 2 GB. I am saving the resulting merged file using the write.csv function.
However, when I check the current directory, it displays "/synfs/notebook/46/aml_notebook_mount", but I cannot locate the saved files in the path I provided or anywhere else. Strangely, when I try to read the file, it successfully loads into a DataFrame within the same Spark session.

Also, I would need to merge about 100 GB of data in the future. What considerations should I keep in mind while undertaking this task?

I need to find the resultant CSV file that was saved. Where does it gets saved?

Comment: Not sure what your code looks like but you are using Mount (streaming), which enables using the dataset exceeding the disk capacity of your VM. Further more, output location can be specified at the time of job submission.

Comment: Your current directory in the sense ml workspace files?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you save using spark context it will saved in that context filesystem.
To see that you need to use below command.

```
%fs ls
```

Below is my dataframe.

[image]

files will be saved in spark context filesystem mounted to it.

[image]

Then, as @Waqas mentioned if the file size exceeds disk capacity may lead error, ensure you have disk capacity available for your future data of 100gb. As you mentioned you have only 2 executors, with the file size you are saying you will get out-of-memory errors, such as `OutOfMemoryError` or `GC Overhead Limit Exceeded`.
So, you need scale up the VM.